# tooltip isnt working when Copytoclipboard in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to copy "reflink" on a button click with a tooltip to pop up after "reflink" was copied

This is my code

```
       <h5 class="card-title">reflink</h5>
       <p class="card-text" style="color:white;" id="reflink" >http://affiliateadvertising.com</p>
       <button onclick="CopyToClipboard('reflink')" ><span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy masternode</span></button>
       <script>
       function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
    range.select().createTextRange();
    document.execCommand("copy");

} else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
     range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
     window.getSelection().addRange(range);
     document.execCommand("copy");
    // alert("text copied")
    var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + copyText.value;
}}

       </script>
```

So i basically want users to be able to just copy their reflink (id="reflink") and than display a tooltip message

Copy to Cliboard is working but i still get this error message in the console

(index):381 Uncaught ReferenceError: copyText is not defined
    at CopyToClipboard ((index):381)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):365)
CopyToClipboard @ (index):381
onclick @ (index):365

Comment: well `copyText` is not defined anywhere in that code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your adapting code from here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_copy_clipboard2 and they're using an input field as the source to copy and its ID is copyText, so you should use your source to get that value, **reflink**

```js
function CopyToClipboard(containerid) {
if (document.selection) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
    range.select().createTextRange();
    document.execCommand("copy");

} else if (window.getSelection) {
    var range = document.createRange();
     range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
     window.getSelection().addRange(range);
     document.execCommand("copy");
    // alert("text copied")
    var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML;
}}
```

```html
      <h5 class="card-title">reflink</h5>
       <p class="card-text" style="color:white;" id="reflink" >http://affiliateadvertising.com</p>
       <button onclick="CopyToClipboard('reflink')" ><span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy masternode</span></button>
```

Comment: all this does is changing the text inside my button to undefined.
i just want a simple tooltip to pop up displaying the copied text

Comment: and what is containerid?

Comment: Did you run the snippet? is working. About your first comment: Just add your CSS to aplly styles to the tooltip. About the second, `containerid` is the parameter sent to the function, so it can select, copy and use the text for the tooltip.

Comment: yes it worked great, thanks. But how come this doesnt work with the id?Why do i have to use containerid? is this a javscript global or something like that?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, at first I've used `text` instead `innerHTML`, so I've editted the answer.